# Is the (left or right) Bol property Isotopy-invariant?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, latin-square, non-associative-algebras, loop-groups

It is well known that a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Loops) satisfies both the left Bol property $(x(yx))z = x(y(xz))$ and the right Bol property $((zx)y)x = z((xy)x)$ if and only if it is a [Moufang loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moufang_loop). It is also well known that the Moufang property is preserved by Loop isotopies.

Are the Left and Right Bol identities preserved individually by Loop Isotopies?